# Angular Universal meta tags not visible in page source

Tags: angular, seo, universal, server-side-rendering

When I view a page where the title and meta tags are set in the constructor of my angular universal project, the title displays in the tab, and I can see the meta tags and title in the html when I click "inspect element" and go to the head of the html document.

However, if you solely click "View Page Source", the tags do not appear, nor does the title. The only things that appear are the original code in index.html.

The universal project compiles fine except when a page is loaded it throws the error
 `"Error: Cannot find module './view/view.module.ngfactory'."`

Perhaps this error has something to do with it. Any thoughts?

Comment: post some code. How do you set the tags? What do you mean with `original code in index.html`?

Comment: I have the same problem, meta tag only appear on inspect element, not in source code, `original code` mean you right click on webpage and chose "View Page Source".

Comment: I have figured out a hacky way of fixing this. Simply add a lot of if statements in the main app.component.ts, and add meta tags based on the route (where the if statements come in). For example, add an if statement saying that if the route is the "about" page, then add a certain type of titlte to the page source.